# Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '(")' not found. 1 pattern tried: ['new_entry'/int:topic_id>/']

Tags: python, django

I am receiving this error when i run my program. The error is said to occur in my topic.html but i am unsure what I typed in wrong for topic_id to return with an empty string.

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """The home page for Test log"""
    return render(request, 'test_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics"""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'test_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'test_logs/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    """Add new topic"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('test_logs:topics')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'test_logs/new_topic.html', context)

def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_vaild():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('test_logs:topic', topic_id==topic_id)
        
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'test_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

*new_entry.html*

```
{% extends "test_logs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<p><a href="{% url '?' %}>">{{ topic }}</a></p>
<p>Add a new entry:</p>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_div }}
add entry
{% endblock content %}
```

I was expecting a new link to appear on the pages where my topics are located to allow users to create new entries in the topic.

*topic.html*

```
{% extends 'test_logs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>
<p>Entries:</p>
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'test_logs:new_entry' topic_id %}">add new entry</a>
</p>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        There are no entires for this topic yet.
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import re_path as URL
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    url(r'^new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
```

Comment: Use `topic.id` in you template as `topic_id` does not exists and has no value.

Comment: i still receive the error when I switch it

Comment: If the problem occur within `new_topic()` function, than it's obvious that you do not pass the topic to the template via context. You only mention in which template you see the error. But you use it in two function and we don't know which causes the problem.

Comment: Btw. `...opic', topic_id==topic_id)` should be `...opic', topic_id=topic_id)`

Answer (score 0):

In the view code, this is how `topic.html` is rendered:

```
context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
return render(request, 'test_logs/topic.html', context)
```

And the problem occurs when `topic.html` tries to display this link:

```
<a href="{% url 'test_logs:new_entry' topic_id %}">add new entry</a>
```

The context does not contain any item named `topic_id`, therefore it tries to use a blank string for that variable.

But the url definition `new_entry/int:topic_id>/` for that view requires `topic_id` to be an integer.  It cannot be blank.  And so it cannot find any matching url definition.

Perhaps you meant `topic.id`, not `topic_id`, in the href link?

Comment: I still receive the same error in the topic.html when I change topic_id to topic.id. I'm not sure if its because of the way I defined the URL definition or something else in the code

Comment: should I change the url def to new_entry/int:topic.id>